# the soot-based flowdroid with an exception error when test an APK

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, dataflow, soot, taint

I am trying to test the broadcast receiver component in an android application based on the taint analysis. However, when i am using the frowdroid to test the related application, it shows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: soot.jimple.infoflow.results.InfoflowResults.getResults()Ljava/util/Map;
    at soot.jimple.infoflow.android.TestApps.Test$MyResultsAvailableHandler.onResultsAvailable(Test.java:80)
    at soot.jimple.infoflow.Infoflow.runAnalysis(Infoflow.java:415)
    at soot.jimple.infoflow.Infoflow.computeInfoflow(Infoflow.java:137)
    at soot.jimple.infoflow.android.SetupApplication.runInfoflow(SetupApplication.java:700)
    at soot.jimple.infoflow.android.TestApps.Test.runAnalysis(Test.java:554)
    at soot.jimple.infoflow.android.TestApps.Test.main(Test.java:217)
```

All the jar files are using the newest nightly version that come from the homepage, but i really have no idea for this kind problem cause I also checked the source code and there is nothing wrong for the `getResult()` method. Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

Question solved, if there are any others have the same problem with `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: soot.jimple.infoflow.results.InfoflowResults.getResults()Ljava/util/Map`.

1. make sure this is the newest jar files that download from the homepage if you are using nightly version.
2. make sure the jar file is not damaged from the homepage sever directly.

Normally if the environment setting is correct, the flowdroid should be alright for running under the nightly jar file.